# Fedora25: SD cauing OS Freeze: dmesg mmc0 error 110

Tags: linux, fedora, freeze, sd-card

After updating my system ( and enabling RPM-Fusion ) I started having strange behavior when plugging in an SD adaptor with its corresponding micro-sd card. Let us rewind a bit though and define strange behavior. Strange behavior in this context consists of a complete loss of GUI and Terminal control. During this time input from the mouse and keyboard is lost and the user must wait for the very very slow mount and reading of the SD card ( in my case it takes upwards 2 minutes for all of this to happen. It used to take zero minutes and zero seconds. ). Another bit of strangeness I noticed is that it no longer extends the kindness of popping up with a notification letting me know that the mount was successful. I thought it may be due to some bad bits on the SD card and used fsck to "remove" the 11 bad bits, but it's still freezing every-single-time. What is going on? Is this a kernel bug and is anybody else experiencing the same problem after upgrading? If it's not a bug and a problem on the users ( my ) end, how can I fix this so I don't have to wait for the computer to pass control back over to the user, you know, like it used to work.

Errors:

```
mmc0: card never left busy state
mmc0: error -110 whilst initializing MMC card
mmc0: error -110 whilst initializing SD card
```

( Side Note ) SD card is still accessible once control is passed back to me and I can add and manipulate files within. It's just during the mount process that the freeze and errors are happening ( Suggesting a software rather than hardware problem )

Toshiba Satellite laptop i3 core.

EDIT: Next day: Update kernel core and some libraries.

New Error:

```
mmc0: error -5 whilst initialising SD card
```

Computer still freezes and a mount notification is not given.